# I don't get FBSDKMessengerShareKit.framework if I use pod

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdkmessengersharekit

Instead of getting the package directly, my project uses pod to get the source code and build it. If I want to use FBSDKMessengerShareKit.framework, the latest pod version doesn't get it. Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Facebook-iOS-SDK/4.0/Facebook-iOS-SDK.podspec.json

Comment: FYI: link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, FBSDKMessengerShareKit is not available on Github or Cocoapods at this time. For now you'll have to download the pkg and link the .framework directly.

Comment: Thank you Chris. A note on fb docs would be helpful to new fb developers like me

Comment: is it possible to continue using 3.x version for everything via pod and only for new messenger functionality use FBSDKMessengerShareKit.framework via pkg. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I think you should be able to use FBSDKMessengerSharerKit with v3.x.

Answer (score 0):

**FBSDKMessengerShareKit** is available under CocoaPods now! Add these to your pod file:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
```

See https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKMessengerShareKit for detail.